# Enabling fullscreen on videos goes to secondary monitor

Tags: video, multiple-monitors

For some reason when I try to go fullscreen while watching videos (HTML5 and Flash), it always initially goes fullscreen on my secondary monitor. When I undo the fullscreen and move the monitor back to my primary monitor and try again it works fine. Is there a fix? I thought it was Flash until I realized YouTube (HTML5 Player) had this issue too.

Here is some info on my setup: I have 3 monitors. Windows numbers them 1,3,2 going from left to right and the middle one (3) is my primary. When I open a video in the side ones (1,2) it opens fullscreen as it should. When I try to open a video on my primary (3), it opens fullscreen on the right side (2)

Comment: Is the secondary monitor set as your main one in settings?

Comment: No. I have 3 monitors. Windows numbers them 1,3,2 going from left to right and the middle one (3) is my primary. When I open a video in the side ones (1,2) it opens fullscreen as it should. When I try to open a video on my primary (3), it opens fullscreen on the right side (2)